# How to clear input text record when i submit to other page and previous page

Tags: c, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

i want to automate to clear record when i submit and previous pages.

```html
model
public class UserClass
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Entry ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Entry Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```html
private readonly ApplicationUserClass _auc;
public abcController(ApplicationUserClass auc)
{
    _auc = auc;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(UserClass uc)
{
    _auc.Add(uc);
    _auc.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```

I see a lot of examples, but not work. Anybody can give advise?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add `ModelState.Clear();` in the post method.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(UserClass uc)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: hi,mj1313,thank you for your help. it is useful for me .thank you so much !

Comment: Hi @ericso, glad that work, could you please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), thank you very much!